# Store number of records returned into a variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

When running the following code

```
DECLARE
        DOCExit varchar2(255);
BEGIN
    IF ( :DOC IS NOT NULL ) THEN
            DOCExit := SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DOCUMENTS WHERE ID=:DOC;
            MESSAGE(DOCExit);
    END IF;
END;
```

I get this error message:

[image]

I'm trying to query the database table `DOCUMENTS` and store number of records return from the query into a variable `DOCExit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SELECT...INTO...`:

```
DECLARE
  DOCExit varchar2(255);
BEGIN
  IF :DOC IS NOT NULL THEN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO DOCExit
      FROM DOCUMENTS
      WHERE ID = :DOC;

    MESSAGE(DOCExit);
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to use INTO clause for any output. In SQL select queries return the values via INTO clause as you can request for multiple columns as well.

```
DECLARE
    DOCExit varchar2(255);
BEGIN
IF ( :DOC IS NOT NULL ) THEN
        SELECT COUNT(*) into DOCExit  FROM DOCUMENTS WHERE ID=:DOC;
        MESSAGE(DOCExit);
END IF;
END;
```